# Different results with different methods of conducting RM ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I have a repeated measures design, one continious outcome "E_R", two categorical predictors "S" and "I". In my design, every participant has been exposed to every level of S and every level of I in random orders (so there's no time variable here).

I have my data in long format with 4 collumns e.g.:

***ID - "I" - "S" - "E_R"***

*1  -  1  -  c  - -32.6*

*1  -  1  -  d  -  6.5*

*1  -  1  -  e  - -4.2*

*1  -  2  -  c  - -8.4*

...

I tried performing the analysis with thee methods I found online.
For two methods I get very similar results (although not exactly the same). But with the third method, I get different results (the conclusions are the same, but the F values are very different).

**Method 1:**

*model <- aov(E_R ~ S * I + Error(ID), data = DF_long)*

*summary(model)*

**Method 2 (with lme4 and lmerTest):**

*model_mixed <- lmer(E_R ~ S * I + (1|ID), data = DF_long)*

*anova(model_mixed)*

**Method 3 (with rstatix):**

*res.aov <- anova_test(
data = DF_long, dv = E_R, wid = ID,
within = c(S, I)
)*

*anova_table <- get_anova_table(res.aov)*

*anova_table*

Here are the results with each method:

***Method 1 results:***

**"S"** Df = 4, Sum Sq = 151817, Mean Sq = 37954, **F value = 32.81**, p < 0.0001

**"I"** Df = 3, Sum Sq = 1097276, Mean Sq = 365759, **F value = 316.15**, p < 0.0001

**"S":"I"** Df = 12, Sum Sq = 11668, Mean Sq = 972, **F value = 0.84**, p = 0.609

**Residuals** Df = 985, Sum Sq = 1139567, Mean Sq = 1157

***Method 2 results:***

**"S"** Sum Sq = 145155, Mean Sq = 36289, NumDF= 4, DenDF = 985.06, **F value = 31.3661**, P < 0.0001

**"I"** Sum Sq = 1093943, Mean Sq = 364648, NumDF= 3, DenDF = 985.05, **F value = 315.1827**, P < 0.0001

**"S":"I"** Sum Sq = 11643, Mean Sq = 970, NumDF= 12, DenDF = 985.07, **F value = 0.8386**, P = 0.6104

***Method 3 results:***

**"S"** DFn = 2.90 , DFd = 113.02, **F = 23.886**, p < 0.0001, ges = 0.05

**"I"** DFn = 1.36, DFd = 53.12, **F = 94.788**, p < 0.0001, ges = 0.305

**"S":"I"** DFn = 7.68 , DFd = 299.67, **F = 1.344**, p = 0.224, ges = 0.007

I'm trying to understand why the results are different, and which one is the correct result. But I can't find anything...
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is it possible that you did not convert the predictors to factor variables before computing the results? It might be possible that Variable I with levels 1, 2, ... is seen as numerical, which would lead to erroneous results with the first two approaches.

Comment: @David I did convert the predictors to factor variables (I just checked). So that's not it...

Comment: I don't use `rstatix`, but a quick look at the manual suggests that you need to specify a random-effect term similar to that you used in Method 1. See the example in the `anova_test` help section on the "formula" argument for "Within-SsANOVA(repeatedmeasuresANOVA)."

Comment: @EdM it doesn't seem to be working. When I use the formula approach I get: Error in Error(ID) : could not find function "Error". 
The manual is inconsistent with the use of the Error term in the formular  it sometimes uses Error() and sometimes error(), I tried both and none of these worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods 1 and 2 are well established, reliable ways to deal with repeated measures. Method 1 can be misleading if there are different numbers of cases in the treatment groups, but that's not a problem in your situation. The results of those two methods agree very closely, as they are essentially the same model specified in different ways.

I'm not a great fan of [`rstatix`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstatix), which you use in Method 3. It's supposed to provide a simpler interface to standard R functions, like those you used in Methods 1 and 2, but I fear that there can be hidden assumptions in the implementation that can lead to this type of discrepancy. And, as you note in a comment, the help file and the actual function don't necessarily agree. Based on what I've seen in answering questions on this site, that package and the similar [`survminer` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survminer), both intended to fit nicely into the "tidyverse," have glitches that recommend against relying on them routinely.

Stick with the more established R functions.

An alternative for repeated measures that you didn't try, but might consider in future work without such a complete data set, is generalized least squares. See Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's [online notes](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long.html) for discussion of different ways to handle such data.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about rstatix, but the first two approaches appear correct to me and produce equivalent results. rstatix is producing different numerator and denominator df.